# How to perform friend search using LIKE and not showing the friends which are already in my friend list?

Tags: java, mysql

My tables look like this:

[image: screenshot of table data]

My `USER_ID` is 1 and I am friend with `USER_ID = 2` and `3`. 
I tried many queries to search all other users name from table "user", which are not in my friend list already. This is one of the query (listed below), tried to use but its showing me duplicate entries

```
select * 
from frnd,user 
where frnd.frnd_id != user.USER_ID 
      AND user.USER_ID != frnd.frnd_id 
      AND frnd.USER_ID = 1 
      AND NAME LIKE '%rah%';
```

And also another problem is, my books (Its for my college project) doesn't tells me anything about `LEFT JOIN`, `JOINS` etc things. Is there a way to get the query for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all other users name from table "user", which are not in my friend list already.

That would be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM user
 WHERE user.user_id NOT IN
        ( SELECT frnd.frnd_id
            FROM frnd
           WHERE user_id = 1
        )
;
```

You probably also want `AND user.user_id != 1`, and of course you can add any other restrictions, such as your `AND name LIKE '%rah%'`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM user
 WHERE user.user_id != 1
   AND user.user_id NOT IN
        ( SELECT frnd.frnd_id
            FROM frnd
           WHERE user_id = 1
        )
   AND user.name LIKE '%rah%'
;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am a student so was not much aware of usage of IN Clause. This will help broaden my thinking with SQL. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use subquery

```
SELECT u.* FROM user u 
WHERE u.user_id != 1 
AND u.user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT f.frnd_id FROM frnd f 
    WHERE f.user_id = 1 
) AND u.user_name LIKE '%rah%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a subquery.
This example will show all people that are not %prash% friends:

```
select * 
from [user]
where USER_ID not in (
    select frnd_id
    from frnd
    where [user_id] in ( select [USER_ID] from [user] where NAME like '%prash%' )
    )
    and NAME not like '%prash%'
```

This will filter both ways without ID's but if you use a search string that will mach more than one user it will filter him out.
You'll have to check how many users mach the search string  and iterate through that.

If you're looking for info about joins and SQL try here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thanks, I have been using w3schools for most of my Language problems.